i can not display the data Stored in sql
@page
@model AfterFix.Pages.Clients.IndexModel
@{
}
@using System.Collections.Generic; 

<br>
<h2>List of Clients</h2>
<a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' href='/Clients/Create'>New Client</a>
<table class="table"> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Created At</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach(var item in Model.listclients)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.id</td>
                <td>@item.name</td>
                <td>@item.email</td>
                <td>@item.phone</td>
                <td>@item.address</td>
                <td>@item.created_at</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="/Clients/Edit?id=@item.id">Edit</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="/Clients/Delete?id=@item.id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace AfterFix.Pages.Clients
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<ClientInfo> listclients = new List<ClientInfo>();
        public void OnGet()
        {
            try
            {
                 string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=mystore;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;Trust Server Certificate=True";
                   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    string sql = "SELECT * From clients";
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                ClientInfo clientInfo = new ClientInfo();
                                clientInfo.id = "" + reader.GetInt32(0);
                                clientInfo.name = reader.GetString(1);
                                clientInfo.email = reader.GetString(2);
                                clientInfo.phone = reader.GetString(3);
                                clientInfo.address = reader.GetString(4);
                                clientInfo.created_at = reader.GetDateTime(5).ToString();
                                listclients.Add(clientInfo);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception : " + ex.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
    public class ClientInfo
    {
        public string id;
        public string name;
        public string email;
        public string phone;
        public string address;
        public string created_at;
    }
}

Dear all, The project is actually working, but I cannot view the data recorded in the database. I have noticed that even if I change the connection statement to another database, the project is not affected, which means that it does not read the database at all.i am using asp.net wep razor pages .Net8 .I only have these two files. Are there any other files that need to be added so that I can view the data?

Have you debugged? What are you getting in reader.Read()? Did you checked  if any error been thrown?

First you should correct your ClientInfo class data types. Id is int32 and Created_at is date , but you defined all parameters of ClientInfo as string.

Second, you can debug your project, using checkpoints at the beginning of the OnGet() procedure and trace the execution flow by F10 to find out if your list parameter (listclients)  is filled correctly or not.


The project is actually working, but I cannot view the data recorded
in the database. I have noticed that even if I change the connection
statement to another database, the project is not affected, which
means that it does not read the database at all.i am using asp.net wep
razor pages .Net8 .I only have these two files. Are there any other
files that need to be added so that I can view the data?

Based on my test, I found the problem within your connection string. I am not sure if you are pointing to right database server.
According to my test, I have following database server and I just replaced my connection string based on my sql server configuration and without any further changes, I can pull data from database using your code.
Here is the steps I did:
Database Configuration:

Connection string:
I have replace my connection string as following:
string connectionString = "Server=(localdb)\\ProjectModels;Database=RazorPageTableJoinDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

Note: Make sure, you are using correct format and right sql server instance credential.
Output:


Note: Please double check your connnection string and format if you are pointing to correct server instance. You could refer to this official document.
